# append values of objects inside array using jq

Tags: jq

I have an object which has an array of objects. I am willing to append two properties of each object inside the array and create a new key out of that. I am new to JQ and have tried various ways to do this, but not able to figure out. Need help.

Input:

```
{
  "name": "Toyota",
  "Model": "Innova",
  "Details": [
    {
      "entry_day": "23",
      "entry_month": "May"
    },
    {
      "entry_day": "01",
      "entry_month": "Jan"
    }
  ]
}
```

Output I expect:

```
{
    "name": "Toyota",
    "Model": "Innova",  
    "Details": [
        {
            "entry_date": "23 May"
        },
        {
            "entry_date": "01 Jan"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your json is invalid: `Jan` and `May` should be in double quotes

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [update assignment operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment) `|=`:

```
jq '(.Details[]|={entry_date:"\(.entry_day) \(.entry_month)"})' input.json
```